# Angular replace existing value in sessionStorage

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several checkbox options defined by event.target.name. when the checkbox is not in session storage, then it will add it to session storage. but if it already exists, it just updates the value. which part should i fix? here is the code that i have made

```
saveSetting(event){
    const getSesssion = sessionStorage.getItem('setting');

    if(getSesssion) {
      const parseSession = JSON.parse(getSesssion);

      parseSession.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.setName === event.target.name) {
          this.changeValue = !this.changeValue;
          item.setValue = this.changeValue;
          parseSession.pipe(map(item => this.settingList.push({ setName: event.target.name, setValue: this.changeValue })));
          sessionStorage.setItem('setting', parseSession);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.settingList.push({ setName: event.target.name, setValue: true });
      const parseList = JSON.stringify(this.settingList);
      sessionStorage.setItem('setting', parseList);
    }
  }
```

I want to replace the value, if it's already in session storage

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the session storage, you can only set and delete data(edit is nothing but set operation). Coming to the logic, you should only push the new obj when it not part of the existing list, else you have to edit the existing item. The below code should work. Let me know if you face any issue.

```
  saveSetting(event){
        const getSesssion = sessionStorage.getItem('setting');
    
        if(getSesssion) {
          const parseSession = JSON.parse(getSesssion);
          let isSetValueExist : boolean = false;
          parseSession.forEach((item : any) => {
    
            if(item.setName === event.target.name) {
              isSetValueExist = true;
              this.changeValue = !this.changeValue;
              item.setName = event.target.name
              item.setValue = this.changeValue;
              sessionStorage.setItem('setting', parseSession);
            }
          });
          if(!isSetValueExist)
          {
                    parseSession.push({ setName: event.target.name, setValue: true });
                    const parseList = JSON.stringify(parseSession);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('setting', parseList);
          }
    
        } else {
          this.settingList.push({ setName: event.target.name, setValue: true });
          const parseList = JSON.stringify(this.settingList);
          sessionStorage.setItem('setting', parseList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: still doesnt work when uncheck checkbox, value not change to false. ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Obj"... is not valid JSON

Comment: can you share me the screenshot of the error?